# ¿Como puedo mostrar una imagen guardada en la base de datos en c# .net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc, entity-framework, asp

tengo un problema con respecto a las imagenes que he guardado en la base de datos para ser mostradas luego en las vistas, en la base de datos he guardado la ruta donde se almacena la imagen y en este caso ha sido en "~/Contents/imgdb/img1.jpg" (forma que guarde la ruta en sqlserver) al momento que el controlador hacer la consulta e ingresa los datos en los models si trae toda la información que he insertado pero no la imagen, no se si la ruta está mal o algo en el controlador o la vista (html) está mal.

adjunto el controlador y el codigo de HTML donde estoy llamando los datos, de esos solo la imagen no me carga lo demás si lo trae sin problemas.

```
 Controlador
 public List<ShowProducts_Result> ListarProducto()
    {
        Datos td = new Datos();
        List<ShowProducts_Result> result = new List<ShowProducts_Result>();

            using (td)
            {
                var listarProductos = td.ShowProducts();

                foreach(var item in listarProductos)
                {
                    var asiganr = new ShowProducts_Result()
                    {
                        IdProducto = item.IdCat,
                        Nombre = item.Nombre,
                        Descripcion = item.Descripcion,
                        Imagen = item.Imagen,
                        precio = item.precio,
                        Exis = item.Exis,
                        Valoracion = item.Valoracion,
                        IdEstado = item.IdEstado,
                        Estado = item.Estado,
                        Cat = item.Cat,
                        IdCat = item.IdCat
                    };
                    result.Add(asiganr);
                }
            }
        return result;
    }
```

Vista HTML

```
<div class="d-flex" style="margin-top: 30px;  padding-right: 30px;">
@{
    List<ShowProducts_Result> result = (List<ShowProducts_Result>)ViewBag.ListarProducto;
    foreach(var item in result)
        {
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="@item.Imagen" alt="Imagen no encontrada...">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">@item.Nombre</h5>
            <p class="card-text">@item.Descripcion</p>
        </div>
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
            <li class="list-group-item">precio: $@item.precio</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Existencias: @item.Exis</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">Valoracion: @item.Valoracion</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="card-body">
            <a href="#" class="card-link">Ver Producto</a>
            <a href="#" class="card-link">Favorito</a>
        </div>
    </div>
        }
}
```

Comment: Puedes ver en tu navegador, en les herramientas para desrrolladores, en la actividad de red, si esta encontrando la imagen con esa url, puedes probar tambien manualmente llamarla con ../contents/blabla o con un @Url.Content(item.Imagen). Tambien tu ruta esta en plural "Contents" es revisar paso a paso. porque en teoria no parece mal.

Comment: lo he resuelto poniendo en la src="~/Content/imgbd/@item.imagen" ha sido de la forma que me ha llamado la imagen. pero dejando la URL directa en la base me dice que no lograba cargar el recurso y de la forma anterior me ha funcionado. gracias por tu ayuda.